# 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name When using PasswordResetConfirmView

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I learned tutorial Django was 3.0.0 and I am with 4.0.1 now. I try to use that module but it not working . I can see the below alert when I am trying to reset my password.
Error : Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

**My urls.py is given below**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path, reverse_lazy
from Core import views 
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordChangeView,
PasswordResetView,
PasswordChangeDoneView, 
PasswordResetConfirmView
from .forms import MyChangePasswordForm,MyPasswordResetForm


app_name ='Core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home, name='home'),
    path('signup/',views.SignupView.as_view(),name='signup'),
    path('login/',views.LoginView.as_view(),name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('change-password/', PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name ='Core/change-password.html',form_class=MyChangePasswordForm, success_url = reverse_lazy('Core:password_change_done')), name='change-password'),
    path('password-change-done/', PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name ='Core/password_change_done.html'), name='password_change_done'),
    
    
    path('reset-password/',PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name = 'Core/password-reset.html',form_class=MyPasswordResetForm),name='reset-password'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('Core:password_reset_confirm')),name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

Comment: You have to use the app name since it's configured, so `reverse("Core:password_reset_confirm")`

Comment: Core is my app name. I used your configured answer but it raised various kinds of problem.

Comment: Can you share the errors? Is it still related to reverse?

Comment: yea, of course .The errors are given below__  
  File "/home/ishak/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 634, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide the _full_ error traceback.

Comment: Ok I will edit it